# Вывести DataFrame в строку без индексов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Имеется `DataFrame df`:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6
0   45  55  65  75  85  95
1   43  53  63  73  83  93
2   47  57  67  77  87  97
3   41  51  61  71  81  91
```

При попытке получения строки:

```
row = df.iloc[0]
```

Выводит вместе с индексом:

```
1    45
2    55
3    65
4    75
5    85
6    95
```

Есть ли возможность вывести без индекса и в строчку, а не в стролбец?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.iloc[0]` возвращает нулевую строку в виде объекта Pandas.Series с именами столбцов в качестве нндексов. Series при выводе на печать показываются вертикально. Чтобы показать строку горизонтально можно "обрамить" номер строки квадратными скобками - в этом случае `.iloc[[...]]` вернет объект типа `DataFrame`:

```
In [6]: df.iloc[[0]]
Out[6]:
    1   2   3   4   5   6
0  45  55  65  75  85  95
```

Pandas всегда выводит индексы для Series и DataFrame's.

Также можно преобразовать Series в 1D Numpy vector:

```
In [7]: df.iloc[0].values
Out[7]: array([45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95], dtype=int64)
```

или в обычный список:

```
In [8]: df.iloc[0].tolist()
Out[8]: [45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95]
```